Extract all the JSON Objects on a set of JSON array inside the JSON Array and remove the duplicates in Athena Query
Hello I am trying to combine the chat history from my report. So the report in the table is save into different data but it has same session ID. I tried query it but I am having issues as it still returning into and array of arrays not objects. This is just a sample data but sometimes when the chat is already to long it still cutting on the middle part only. I want to remove the duplicates and just show the whole chat. Any recommendations what can be done on this?
WITH session_data AS (
    SELECT
        sessionid,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                        REGEXP_REPLACE(
                            COALESCE(responsechatmessagehistory, ''), 
                            '\\\\', '' -- Remove all backslashes first
                        ), 
                        '\\n\\n', ' '), -- Replace double newlines with a space
                    '\\n', ' '), -- Replace remaining newlines with a space
                '\\r|\\t', ''), -- Remove carriage returns and tabs
            '\\s{2,}', ' ' -- Replace multiple spaces with a single space
        ) AS cleaned_response_chat_history,
        COALESCE(responselastseen, '') AS valid_responselastseen,
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(requestfirstseen, '') <> '' THEN requestfirstseen
            ELSE NULL
        END AS valid_firstseen
    FROM "AwsDataCatalog"."app_qna_bot_iris_dev_qnabot_glue_db"."app_qna_bot_iris_dev_transformedmetrics"
),
ordered_data AS (
    SELECT
        sessionid,
        MIN(valid_firstseen) AS earliest_firstseen,
        MAX(valid_responselastseen) AS latest_responselastseen,
        ARRAY_AGG(cleaned_response_chat_history ORDER BY valid_responselastseen ASC) AS chat_history_array
    FROM session_data
    GROUP BY sessionid
    HAVING MIN(valid_firstseen) IS NOT NULL
),
unnested_chats AS (
    SELECT
        sessionid,
        earliest_firstseen,
        latest_responselastseen,
        chat_element, -- The JSON object already containing Human and AI
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sessionid ORDER BY earliest_firstseen) AS row_num
    FROM ordered_data
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(chat_history_array) AS t (chat_element)
)
SELECT
    sessionid,
    earliest_firstseen,
    latest_responselastseen,
    CONCAT('[', ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(chat_element ORDER BY row_num), ','), ']') AS fullchat_history
FROM unnested_chats
GROUP BY sessionid, earliest_firstseen, latest_responselastseen
ORDER BY latest_responselastseen
LIMIT 20;


Currently the result is like this
[
  [
    { "Human": "what is icompany?" },
    {
      "AI": "Brilliant question! icompany is an innovative company that helps businesses digitise their contact centres using AI, automation, and analytics. Founded in, icompany offers services like Amazon Connect, AI solutions, and custom software development to accelerate digital growth for clients globally. Would you like me to dive deeper into icompany's offerings?"
    }
  ],
  [
    { "Human": "what is icompany?" },
    {
      "AI": "Brilliant question! icompany is an innovative company that helps businesses digitise their contact centres using AI, automation, and analytics. Founded in, icompany offers services like Amazon Connect, AI solutions, and custom software development to accelerate digital growth for clients globally. Would you like me to dive deeper into icompany's offerings?"
    },
    { "Human": "yes" },
    {
      "AI": "Absolutely! Here's a more comprehensive look at icompany: - icompany is a **business process ** that empowers clients to **digitise their contact centre operations** using **artificial intelligence, automation, and analytics** - It was established in **2022** by experienced leaders from the **US** with the vision of **accelerating digital growth for clients** - icompany offers services like:     - **Amazon Connect Unleashed** - Leveraging Amazon's cloud contact centre solution     - **AI Design and Operations** - Implementing AI solutions for business processes     - **Customised Software Development** tailored to specific business requirements - The company is **headquartered in US** with operations in the **US supporting clients globally** icompany aims to be a trusted partner for businesses looking to undergo digital transformation and optimise their customer experience through innovative technologies. Would you like me to provide more details on booking an appointment with our experts or requesting a quotation for icompany's services?"
    }
  ]
]


[
  
    { "Human": "what is icompany?" },
    {
      "AI": "Brilliant question! icompany is an innovative company that helps businesses digitise their contact centres using AI, automation, and analytics. Founded in, icompany offers services like Amazon Connect, AI solutions, and custom software development to accelerate digital growth for clients globally. Would you like me to dive deeper into icompany's offerings?"
    },
    { "Human": "yes" },
    {
      "AI": "Absolutely! Here's a more comprehensive look at icompany: - icompany is a **business process ** that empowers clients to **digitise their contact centre operations** using **artificial intelligence, automation, and analytics** - It was established in **2022** by experienced leaders from the **US** with the vision of **accelerating digital growth for clients** - icompany offers services like:     - **Amazon Connect Unleashed** - Leveraging Amazon's cloud contact centre solution     - **AI Design and Operations** - Implementing AI solutions for business processes     - **Customised Software Development** tailored to specific business requirements - The company is **headquartered in US** with operations in the **US supporting clients globally** icompany aims to be a trusted partner for businesses looking to undergo digital transformation and optimise their customer experience through innovative technologies. Would you like me to provide more details on booking an appointment with our experts or requesting a quotation for icompany's services?"
    }
]


Please add some sample data and desired outputs (and the rules to transform one into another)
